# mysql: Not able to create a table

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064

```
create table 5390e910_abb3_40e2_bdfa_bd9d369e6dc6 like sample_table
```

is failing.

> ERROR: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual
>   that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to
>   use near '5390e910_abb3_40e2_bdfa_bd9d369e6dc6 like
>   notification_sample_history' at line 1

Now I don't see any flaw with the above name as the mysql documentation says:

1. 64 characters max
2. can start with any alphabet/digit
3. an contain underscores/alphabets/digits

Though I am able to run something like this:

```
create table 1f8b784f_f580_4a82_9e93_167a2d9c79f5 like  sample_table
```

Comment: Your error message (`like notification_sample_history`) does not match your given statement (`like sample_table`) Please post the *exact* statement which is causing the error.

Comment: What a good descriptive names of a table you use. Look forward to maintaining that schema

Comment: The real problem here is the name of the table - why on earth name it like that?

Comment: @juergend - It's clearly a UUID, and he's clearly doing some sort of automated / programmatic schema DDL, using sample_table as a template to set up a new entity/data storage table during a runtime.   Maybe an X/Y problem, but the question is valid.

Comment: Anyway, OP - try quoting the table name.   mysql docs indicate the table name must be quoted if it "consists only of digits".   Maybe it means "digits and underscores and some hex digits that aren't digits also" or something.   Who knows?

Comment: @DarwinvonCorax Will take care next time. Thank you anyways! : )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe it's the first "e".  When I swap that character for any other letter, the query works just fine.

I'm not positive on this, but my *suspicion* is that MySQL is reading your string and considering it to mean the number "5,390 times 10 to the power of 910abb3[etc]".  And while all-numeric table names are valid they must be quoted.

Try enclosing your table name in back-ticks.  This works for me:

```
create table `5390e910_abb3_40e2_bdfa_bd9d369e6dc6` like abbreviations;
```

Comment: It's a power of 10, not a power of `e`. It's normal floating point literal syntax, `2e20` means 2 times 10 to the 20th power.

Comment: gah.  Yes, you're right.  Brain cramp, sorry.  I'll fix.

Comment: I was using ' instead of ` .
It's working fine. Thanks